# How to show a field from the current node in quicktabs

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a quicktabs block on the node page which will have several tabs with different views/content related to the current node. How can I show a field from that node in a separate tab?

Comment: you should use views arguments

Comment: how views arguments will help me? can you give more details please.

Answer (score 1):

Depend from requirements in the project, but [Field Group](https://drupal.org/project/field_group) can be an option too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Field As Block module (https://drupal.org/project/fieldblock)
2. In the Manage Display section of your content type, check the "Display As Block" checkbox next to the field you want to display in a quicktab
3. Add a tab to your quick tab with a tab type of block then select your field from the list of blocks.

The Field As Block module will create a block from the node's field.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little overkill for just showing only one field but here's how I 'd do it.
Create a view block with a nid contextual argument. Add the desired field you want to display to the views fields. Then from the quicktabs administration create a tab that will use the view you just created.

The block should grab the nid from the node you are and display accordingly the content of the field.

Comment: This does sound like an overkill. I was actually thinking of creating blocks, that will pull corresponding fields. It will be much less code.

Comment: Indeed. You can pull the nid from the url and render the specific field you want programmaticaly. Nevertheless with views you get the advantage of fast configuration with no code, easy styling, adding classes and all of the possible features Views offer. After all with caching the overall overload could be minimum. From what I can remember quicktabs offer ajax for loading the content. Maybe after all its not so overkill. Your choice.

Comment: I was thinking of this CCK Blocks module - http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks

Comment: It says CCK Blocks module doesn't work with caching. Not a bad idea though. Its up to you. Try out what serves you better.

Comment: I will do this with custom code.